# PowerBI Getting ERROR A function 'CALCULATE' has been used

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I would like to show the card values:

- if current month value is not available then it should compare with the previous month value automatically.

Like

[image]

In above image Apr-2017 value is not available then it should compare with the Mar-2017 value.

If Mar-2017 value also not available then the previous month value.Keep on goes.
And one more thing is I don't want to use the slicer anymore. Actually I am not going to use the slicer.

I just want to show the month comparison value in a card visuals.

I would like to give info of what kind of data that I have. I have table's plan rev, actual rev, and MonthYear

I have created a relationship using Date column from MonthYear table to plan rev and actual rev Date columns.

MonthYear table

[image]

And in plan rev, month year, plan rev, date, and in actual rev actual rev, month year, and date columns.

Then written measures for

```
 For Sumof Plan rev-->
 PlanSum = SUM('Revenue Report'[Planned Rev])
   For Prev month value-->
 PlanPrevMon = CALCULATE([PlanSum],PREVIOUSMONTH('Month Year'[Date]))
```

For Start and End Date of the months

```
FILTERDATESTART= FIRSTDATE('MonthYear'[Date])
FILTERDATEEND= LASTDATE('MonthYear'[Date])
```

Then for current month PlanArrows measure is.

```
PlanArrows = CALCULATE(
    IF(
        ISBLANK([PlanSum]),"No data Available",[PlanSum]
    )& " "& IF(
        [PlanSum]=[PlanPrevMon],
        "",
        IF([PlanSum]>[PlanPrevMon],
            UNICHAR(8679),
            UNICHAR(8681)
        ) & IF([PlanSum]<=0,
        "",""
        )
    ),
    'Month Year'[Date]>=FILTERDATESTART, 
        'Month Year'[Date]<=FILTERDATEEND
)
```

But it is not working. I'm getting an error:

> A function 'CALCULATE' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.

Any Suggestions please,

Thanks

Mohan V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i got the solution on my own.
I have written measure which solved this issue.

```
PlanArrows =
VAR s = [FILTERDATESTART]
VAR e = [FILTERDATEEND]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        IF ( ISBLANK ( [PlanSum] ), "No data Available", [PlanSum] ) & " "
            & IF (
                [PlanSum] = [PlanPrevMon],
                "",
                IF ( [PlanSum] > [PlanPrevMon], UNICHAR(8679), UNICHAR(8681) )
                    & IF ( [PlanSum] <= 0, "", "" )
            ),
        'Month Year'[Date] >= s
            && 'Month Year'[Date] <= e
    )
```